# getting error in doing operations of http url operation in android

Tags: android

I am trying to send sms from my android app but getting the error.
i am using **AsyncTask** class and the code which put in **doInBackground method** it gives an error.

PLEASE HELP ME I HAVE PURCHASED THE SMS SERVICE BUT I AM NOT BEING ABLE TO MAKE CALL OF SERVICE.

SendFeedback class

```
private class SendfeedbackJob extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {
        // do above Server call here

        try {
            // Construct data
            String apiKey = "apikey=" + "--MY API KEY--";
            String message = "&message=" + "New order by "+ userName+" 
            and dilivery "+userAddress;
            String sender = "&sender=" + "TXTLCL";
            String numbers = "&numbers=" + "91 CONTACT NO.";

            // Send data
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new 
            URL("https://api.textlocal.in/send/?").openConnection();
            String data = apiKey + numbers + message + sender;
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", 
            Integer.toString(data.length()));
            conn.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            final StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();

            //return stringBuffer.toString();




            Toast.makeText(getContext(),stringBuffer.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error SMS "+e);
            //return "Error "+e;
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error 
            "+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return "some message";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
        //process message

    }
}
```

Oncreate method

```
SendfeedbackJob job = new SendfeedbackJob();
job.execute();
```

I am getting this Error

```
'E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
              Process: com.agssoftech.shlokenterprise, PID: 12204
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing 
doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
                  at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                  at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                  at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                  at 
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                  at 

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                  at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cant create handler 
inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:208)
                  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:122)
                  at android.widget.Toast$TN$2.<init>(Toast.java:341)
                  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:341)
                  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:108)
                  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:261)
                  at com.agssoftech.shlokenterprise.Fragments
.PlaceOrderFragment$SendfeedbackJob.doInBackground
(PlaceOrderFragment.java:224)
                  at 
com.agssoftech.shlokenterprise.Fragments
.PlaceOrderFragment$SendfeedbackJob.doInBackground
(PlaceOrderFragment.java:190)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
                  at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at 
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                  at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `Toast.makeText()` from the `doInBackground` method as it is not running on the UI thread. 
Move your calls to `Toast.makeText()` to the `onPostExecute` method, which runs on the UI thread.